# Maximum number of decision variables in scipy linear programming module in python

Tags: scipy, linear-programming, scipy-optimize

Is there any maximum limit for decision variables in scipy linear programming module (minimization) in python? If so, Can it be extended the number of decision variables to 10000? If scipy is limited to number of decision variables, Is there any other software which can be installed in python so that I can proceed with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original scipy Simplex LP solver was only for very small problems. The newer scipy  Interior Point solver can handle larger problems more reliably. Also make sure to pass on A_eq and/or A_ub as sparse matrices. If you don't do this you may run out of memory.

Having said this, I would be more comfortable with LP solvers that have seen more large, sparse problems than scipy. Most LP solvers have a Python interface.

Finally, larger problems are often (but not always) more complex and it may help to use a modeling tool. This will allow you to express the problem in a more natural way than using matrices. For Python there is PuLP and Pyomo (among others). Some commercial solvers also provide excellent modeling tools.

Comment: I am working on optimal transportation problem in which a part requires LP solving. As my entire code is in python, Yes I tried simplex as you pointed out the maximum i can go is around 625 and sometimes lesser than that.I am looking for a software which is freely available and can be installed in python. Thanks in advance

Comment: The transportation problem is a very simple, and very sparse LP (2 nonzeros per column). An interior point solver should do good on this. There are faster, more specialized algorithms for this problem.

Comment: Can we implement this in python ? I tried with interior point method in scipy python linear programming module.. I couldn't do it beyond 625 decisive variables. It fails again. Kindly let me know which module could be used so that I can increase number of decisive variables. @Erwin

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. I can solve transportation problems with 1000 supply nodes and 1000 demand nodes with `scipy.optimize.linprog`. I.e. the LP has 1 million variables and 2k constraints. I made sure the matrix was passed on as a sparse CSC matrix (`scipy.sparse`), I used 64 bit python 3.7.

Comment: See [link](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2019/10/scipy-linear-programming-large-but-easy.html) for details.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks for your link. Though the code runs and gives the answer. It throws the warning message which is as follows: " C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_linprog_ip.py:643: OptimizeWarning: A_eq does not appear to be of full row rank. To improve performance, check the problem formulation for redundant equality constraints.
  warn(redundancy_warning, OptimizeWarning)".. What does this mean? Can you please explain

Comment: I think you can see that when you give it the equality formulation of the transportation problem. If you transform it into an inequality format, the message will likely go away. I would not worry about this warning for this particular case.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have used equality constraint. I need another clarification. What should be the configuration of the laptop/desktop to run million decisive variable optimal transport problems? My laptop configuration is Intel 5 processor 10th generation, 8GB RAM, 1TB + 256 SSD hard disk. My code is still running for more than 10 hours for 1000 x 1000 Linear programming problem. What is the system requirement to run million variable LP problem for OT ? Please advise me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, I took a simple problem of computing Wasserstein distance between two one dimensional Gaussian probability distribution with different mean and variance for that distribution. Kindly clarify my issue on the requirement of configuration for LP problem with million problems

Comment: I guess, if you cannot even compute the distances, there is no need to worry about solving the LP.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I don't understand. Closed-form solutions do exist between two Gaussian distributions for simple quadratic distances between this (Wasserstein Distance). For simpler 10000 decisive variables it gives answers in 10 mins. For larger matrices like million variables it has been running for 16 hours and still running. I really don't know when it will show the results. I need to know whether it requires a system with a large RAM size? What system configuration is required to run million variable problem? I m using intel 5,10th gen, 8GB RAM.